How to send large amount of data with CFSocketSendData without blocking
I want to write potentially large amounts of data over a TCP socket, without blocking the sending thread. I'm using a CFSocket.
With the send function I can do non-blocking writes. That function either returns the number of bytes actually transferred to the underlying layer (possibly some but not all bytes), or uses EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK to indicate that I need to wait for a write-notification.
With CFSocketSendData I don't understand how this can be accomplished, because the API does not seem to offer a way of indicating a partial write. Is there something I'm missing, or do I need to switch mindsets/use some other API (like Network)?

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket is deprecated, with no mention of a replacement. I noticed this question in which the original poster gives up and resorts to a non-Apple solution.
My current best plan is to punch a hole with CFSocketGetNative and revert to send. But I hope I'm missing something here...
